# Add prerequisites to viewing webpages

Tags: javascript, html, moodle, scorm

I am currently looking to develop some SCORM compliant documents to be used within a Moodle 2.2 environment (learning management system) however SCORM 2004 is not fully supported which means the sequencing of pages is not possible.

As an alternative I was thinking of moving away from SCORM and developing a standard set of webpages which does not track a users progress but does add sequencing prerequisites to be used within Moodle.

I imagine this is possible with Javascript however I am unsure how to approach this. Can anybody suggest scripts already out there which might provide this functionality?

Many thanks,
Dan

Comment: What kind of sequencing rules do you need for your content? Can you give an example?

Comment: If you have four pages which all act as a lesson for a course, in order to view page two you must have viewed page one, and if you wish to view page three you must have viewed page one and two, and so on. I hope this helps!

Comment: I think you can do this in SCORM 1.2 with a multi-SCO and using adlcp:prerequisites

Comment: Aha. That would be excellent. I'll look into it and report anything I find. Thanks!

Comment: What you suggested worked a treat. Much appreciated

Comment: ok I'll post it as an answer so you can accept and close this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you consider to use some other module than SCORM, take a look at these:

- Book http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Book_module
- Lesson http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Lesson_module
- Questionnaire http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Questionnaire_module

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in SCORM 1.2 with a multi-SCO and using adlcp:prerequisites